# Get the data form the innermost brackets

Tags: python

I have a text file with the following data

```
This is the first line 
This is the second line 
This is the third line 
Book1
{
    {
        {
             {Chapter 1, 10, numbers}
             {Chapter 2, 20, numbers}
             {Chapter 3, 30, numbers}
             {Chapter 4, 40, numbers}
        }
       {
            {Chapter 5, 50, numbers}
            {Chapter 6, 60, numbers}
            {Chapter 7, 70, numbers}
            {Chapter 8, 80, numbers}
        }
    }
}
```

From the above data I need to get the data in the innermost “{}” 
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
import re
preg = re.compile(r'\{([^{}]+)\}')
for match in preg.finditer(your_text):
    print(match.group(1))
```

Maybe [this interactive explanation](https://regex101.com/r/fC6bA6/1) will help understanding the logic behind the regex.

Comment: Thank you so much Finwood, it just worked perfectly :)  and one more doubt how can i separate chapter 1 to 4 as one group and chapter 5 to 8 as another ?